# How to update a boolean value with mongoid and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I've got a preliminary boolean value for "published" set to 'false' from a previous posting, but from this PREVIEW screen I'd like to allow the user to update this value to 'true' by clicking to have this post published, but am having difficulties.

VIEW - preview.html.erb

```
<div class="preview clearfix">
        <%= form_for @job, url: '/jobs/publish/' do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :publish, :value => true %>

        <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i> Review your job post! If approved, submit it, or cancel and try again.</span>

        <%= f.submit "Post Job", :class => 'btn btn-default btn-sm' %>
        <a href="/jobs/new" class="btn" style="margin-top:3px;">Cancel</a>

        <% end %>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER - jobs_controller.rb

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @jobs = Job.all #where(publish: true)
end

def show
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
end

def new
end

def preview
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    job = Job.new
    job.job_title = params[:job][:job_title]
    job.job_location = params[:job][:job_location]
    job.job_description = params[:job][:job_description]
    job.job_responsibilities = params[:job][:job_responsibilities]
    job.job_requirements = params[:job][:job_requirements]
    job.specialties = params[:job][:specialties]
    job.job_level = params[:job][:job_level]
    job.how_to_apply = params[:job][:how_to_apply]
    job.company = params[:job][:company]
    job.company_description = params[:job][:company_description]
    job.company_website = params[:job][:company_website]
    job.avatar = params[:job][:avatar]
    job.agree = params[:job][:agree]
    job.publish = false
    job.save!
    redirect_to '/jobs/preview/' + job.id
end

def update
    job = Job.find(params[:id])  ## Using "find"
    job.publish = true
    job.save!
    redirect_to '/jobs'
end

end
```

ROUTE

```
  post 'jobs/publish/' => 'jobs#update'
```

MODEL - job.rb

```
class Job
include Mongoid::Document
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

field :job_title, type: String
field :job_location, type: String
field :job_description, type: String
field :job_responsibilities, type: String
field :job_requirements, type: String
field :specialties, type: String
field :job_level, type: String

field :how_to_apply, type: String

field :company, type: String
field :company_description, type: String
field :company_website, type: String

field :agree, type: Boolean

field :publish, type: Boolean

end
```

LOGS

Processing by GridfsController#avatar as JPEG
  Parameters: {"id"=>"53c985c36d7572b6cd000000", "filename"=>"cuben-rustic"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=ffos_development collection=jobs selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('53c985c36d7572b6cd000000')} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 2.8140ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=ffos_development collection=fs.files selector={"$query"=>{"filename"=>"uploads/job/avatar/53c985c36d7572b6cd000000/cuben-rustic.jpg"}, "$orderby"=>{"uploadDate"=>-1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.4260ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=ffos_development command={:count=>"fs.chunks", :query=>{"files_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('53c985c36d7572b6cd020000')}} runtime: 0.3460ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=ffos_development collection=fs.chunks selector={"$query"=>{"files_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('53c985c36d7572b6cd020000'), "n"=>{"$lt"=>7, "$gte"=>0}}, "$orderby"=>{"n"=>1}} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 8.0450ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 GET_MORE     database=ffos_development collection=fs.chunks limit=0 cursor_id=120760258650 runtime: 1.8960ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=ffos_development command={:count=>"fs.chunks", :query=>{"files_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('53c985c36d7572b6cd020000')}} runtime: 0.4970ms
  Rendered text template (0.3ms)
Sent data  (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 0.6ms)

Started GET "/uploads/job/avatar/53c98e5a6d7572b9c6000000/cuben-rustic.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-18 14:30:18 -0700
Processing by GridfsController#avatar as JPEG
  Parameters: {"id"=>"53c98e5a6d7572b9c6000000", "filename"=>"cuben-rustic"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=ffos_development collection=jobs selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('53c98e5a6d7572b9c6000000')} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.4900ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=ffos_development collection=fs.files selector={"$query"=>{"filename"=>"uploads/job/avatar/53c98e5a6d7572b9c6000000/cuben-rustic.jpg"}, "$orderby"=>{"uploadDate"=>-1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.5350ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=ffos_development command={:count=>"fs.chunks", :query=>{"files_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('53c98e5a6d7572b9c6020000')}} runtime: 0.7430ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=ffos_development collection=fs.chunks selector={"$query"=>{"files_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('53c98e5a6d7572b9c6020000'), "n"=>{"$lt"=>7, "$gte"=>0}}, "$orderby"=>{"n"=>1}} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 6.5520ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 GET_MORE     database=ffos_development collection=fs.chunks limit=0 cursor_id=120550877243 runtime: 1.9530ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=ffos_development command={:count=>"fs.chunks", :query=>{"files_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('53c98e5a6d7572b9c6020000')}} runtime: 0.4840ms
  Rendered text template (0.2ms)
Sent data  (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 0.5ms)

Comment: Could you post as well Job model?

Comment: I've added the model.

Comment: What is the exact problem that you are facing? Are you receiving any error? If so, please add it in the question.

Comment: No errors. The problem is that the code is NOT changing the boolean value for 'publish' from false to true. It goes through without a problem, but it just doesn't update. Somehow I need my controller to just update the boolean value from false to true for the specific job.

Comment: My guess is that maybe the ID of the job isn't being attributed to the update?  I just don't know.

Comment: Can you share the server logs generated for the `update` action when you try to update a record. Add it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I had to pass the job ID from the preview page to the controller again.

```
<%= form_for @job, url: '/jobs/publish/'+@job.id do |f| %>
```

And then revised the controller to:

```
def update
    job = Job.find(params[:id])
    job.publish = true
    job.save!
    redirect_to '/jobs'
end
```

And change the route to "patch":

```
patch '/jobs/publish/:id' => 'jobs#update'
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems that I notice is that you are using `find_by` method incorrectly in order to locate the `Job` record. If you have to use `find_by` then you must specify the *attribute name* of that Model based on which you are searching, which is missing in your case.

A better option would be to use `find` method as you are searching based on primary key `id` i.e., `params[:job][:id]` refers to the `id` of a particular `Job` record.

What you need to do is, replace

```
job = Job.find_by(params[:job][:id])
```

With

```
job = Job.find(params[:job][:id])  ## Using "find"
```

-OR-

```
job = Job.find_by(id: params[:job][:id])  ## Using "find_by" - specify attribute name "id"
```

Comment: I get an error with that replacement. Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind in JobsController#update

Comment: Problem: Calling Document.find with nil is invalid. Summary: Document.find expects the parameters to be 1 or more ids, and will return a single document if 1 id is provided, otherwise an array of documents if multiple ids are provided. Resolution: Most likely this is caused by passing parameters directly through to the find, and the parameter either is not present or the key from which it is accessed is incorrect.